# Mutably passing an immutably borrowed variable

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a simple memoisation-style call loop. It looks something like this:

```
fn dive(seen: u32, d: u32, r: u32, routes: &mut HashMap<(u32, u32), u32>) -> u32 {
    match routes.get(&(cmp::max(d, r), cmp::min(d, r))) {
    Some(v) => seen + *v,
    None => {
        let result = dive(0, d-1, r, routes) + dive(0, d, r-1, routes);
        routes.insert((cmp::max(d, r), cmp::min(d, r)), result);
        seen + result
    }
}
```

However, I am having issues because routes is borrowed immutably for the match, and then passed mutably for the following `dives` whilst still in a valid lifetime.

How can I get this to work? Can it be fixed by simply 'copying' the immutable value somehow? Or do I need to fix the control flow?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to fix the missing curly brace and possibly indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that this has been answered before, but searching for it is not proving fruitful. If anyone finds a dupe, feel free to mark this as such.

The problem is that in Rust, borrow scopes are currently *lexical* — they correspond to regions of code, ending at a closing curly brace.

In your example, the borrow of `routes` lasts for the entire `match` block, which includes the `None` case. A smarter compiler would be able to see that the `None` case has no references to the `routes` and allow you to change it. For now, you have to make your code a bit uglier:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::cmp;

fn dive(seen: u32, d: u32, r: u32, routes: &mut HashMap<(u32, u32), u32>) -> u32 {
    let key = (cmp::max(d, r), cmp::min(d, r));

    if let Some(v) = routes.get(&key) {
        return seen + *v;
    }

    let result = dive(0, d-1, r, routes) + dive(0, d, r-1, routes);
    routes.insert(key, result);
    seen + result
}

fn main() {}
```

This splits up the code into two distinct scopes, clarifying that the borrow only is needed in the first one.

There is hope for this to change. The original issue was [borrow scopes should not always be lexical](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/6393), which was closed in favor of [an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811). At the current point in time, the RFC is postponed. Unfortunately, changing from lexical to non-lexical scopes for borrows has the potential to make certain types of things harder to reason about.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I do wish the compiler was a little bit smarter about these kind of things - it sucks having to pull out of a nice match loop just to appease it :P

Comment: Couldn't this be rewritten with entries API? I think it solves exactly this problem (and given `Copy` keys it is rather easy to use). (BTW, you didn't reuse the `key` in `insert`).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev good point, I forgot about the entry API here, as I was focused on the borrow issue. However, since `routes` is passed down to the recursive call, it doesn't like it. [Did I miss something](http://is.gd/dHpmeQ)?

Comment: Oh, indeed, I somehow missed the recursion bit. In this case you're right, I don't think it's possible to use entries, unfortunately.